# Creating a 2D 'board' using list comperhension - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I create such board using list comperhension?

```
board = [[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4)],
         [(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)],
         [(2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4)],
         [(3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4)],
         [(4,0), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list-comprehension to achieve this as follows.
Run the for loop for the 2nd index in a inner list comprehension, and the for loop for the 1st index in the outer list comprehension

```
board = [ [(j,i) for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
print(board)
```

The output will be

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)], 
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)], 
[(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)], 
[(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)], 
[(4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]]
```